# Python - I was given pickle files that contain XGBoost models. How do I find the details of the file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

For a work project, I was given two pickle files. I was told that these pickles have XGBoost models so I installed XGBoost. I was able to load them using this command

```
import pickle
filename = 'model.pickle'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
print(type(loaded_model))
```

which produces

```
<class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier'>
```

However, I don't know what the name of the inputs that are required to run this model. I found this command from another XGBoost tutorial here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-gradient-boosting-models-xgboost-python/:

```
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

But this does not work as the X_test and y_test are not defined. I need to find out the actual names of X_test and y_test sets as well as the contains of the pickle. Also, how do I explore the contents of this pickle? I would like to view everything inside this XGBoost pickle.

Comment: pls use tag wisely; the fact that you may work in Spyder does not make this a `spyder` question (removed)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. X_test and y_test are not defined because you didn't define them. You had 2 pickle files which contains xgboost object NOT testing features and testing labels.
   If you want to "test" the model you've recieved, create X_test and y_test and test your model.
2. If you want to know more about the xgboost object you've recieved, I suggest using xgboost API which can be found [**here**](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster). For example, `loaded_model.feature_names` will return a list of feature names if one defined it. `loaded_model.dump_model` will save a .txt file containing all the trees.
3. [**Here**](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) you can read about Scikit-Learn API, and more specifically, about the `xgboost.XGBClassifier` class.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that I misunderstood the X_test and y_test parts. I will read the links and I will follow up once I get this running.